# Creating Linked list insertion function but the code is not running

Tags: c++, insert, linked-list

Unable to recognize the error in creating a linked list insertion function in linked list class the compiler giving this " error: qualified-id in declaration before '(' token But it seems like all the parenthesis are placed correctly.

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;
    void additem();
    void deleteitem();
    void searchitem(int x);

struct student{
int data;
int * next;
};

   student * head;
   student * curr;

int main()
{
   int x;
   cout << "To add item type 1" << endl;
   cin >> x;

   switch(x)
   {
     case 1:
     additem();
   }

    return 0;
}


void additem()
{
    student * temp;

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        temp = new student;
        head = temp;
        curr = temp;
        temp->next = NULL;
        cout << "Enter data" << endl;
        cin >> temp->data << endl;
    }

    else if(head != NULL)
    {
         temp = new student;
         curr->next = temp;
         curr = temp;
         temp->next = NULL;
         cout << "Enter data" << endl;
         cin >> temp->data ;
    }
    else{
        break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring a class and methods within `main`.  This is not allowed (nested functions).  `linkedlist::additem` needs to be defined before main.

Comment: @MAhmadRana What does your code look like now, and where exactly are you getting the error in it?